# Vanishing of Ext sheaves above Krull dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $M$ is a module over a regular local ring $A$, then the projective dimension of $M$, denoted $\textrm{pd }M$, is bounded above by the Krull dimension of $A$: $$\textrm{pd }M\leq \dim A.$$ This inequality is equivalent to $\textrm{Ext}^i_A(M,-)=0$, for all $i>\dim A$.

> Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and $M$ a coherent sheaf on
>   $X$. Is it true that $\mathcal Ext^i_X(M,-)=0$ for $i>\dim X$? Or is
>   any assumption on $M$ needed?

Taking stalks, I see that $\mathcal Ext^i_X(M,N)_x=\textrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal O_{X,x}}(M_x,N_x)$, and this should vanish because $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is regular of dimension $\dim X$. Is this argument enough?

Thanks!

Comment: Your argument is fine, sheaf ext calculations for coherent sheaves are purely local. So, you also don't need the hypothesis of projectivity, quasi-projective would be more than enough.